# C# Get specific char from a custom font and insert it into string

Tags: c#, .net, fonts, pdfsharp, migradoc

I have such string "my profeesion is - G", I need to replace "G" with custom font symbol. In custom font this char is an icon. So result should be like "my profeesion is - 'ICON AT G INDEX AT CUSTOM FONT'". Thanks.

Comment: This depends upon what your are displaying the text in?

Comment: @AlexK. I gonna use it in migraDoc paragraphs(which is related to pdf and pdfsharp library). Paragraph has property font and I can set it. But if I just set it all text will use that font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `AddFormattedText()` method of the `Paragraph` class to mix several styles/fonts within a single paragraph.

See also:
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/MigraDocFirstSteps.ashx
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/HelloMigraDoc-sample.ashx